# degree of morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $\phi: Y \to X$ be a finite etale morphism of proper smooth connected schemes over a field $K$ and suppose that the induced morphism $\phi: \overline{Y} \to \overline{X}$ has degree $n$, where $\overline{Y} = Y \times_K \bar{K}$ etc.

> Can I conclude that $\phi$ has degree $\leq n$? If not, what other conditions should I impose so that this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77594

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes** under much broader assumptions.

Indeed, if $\phi:Y\to X$ is a completely arbitrary finite étale morphism of degree $n$, then $X$ can be covered  by affine open subsets $U=\text {Spec}(A)$ such that $\phi^{-1}(U)=\text {Spec} (B)$ is affine with $B$ a free separable $A$-algebra  of dimension $n$.
Hence  **for any base change $X'\to X$** the resulting morphism $X'\times_X Y\to X'$ is again finite étale of degree n: the underlying algebraic reason being that for **any** $A$-algebra $A'$, the $A'$-algebra $A'\otimes_A B$ is separable and  free of dimension $n$ too.

In conclusion, the degree of a finite étale map is invariant under base change, which of course answers your question.

**Remark**
This answer illustrates the weird fact that often in algebraic geometry (and  elsewhere in mathematics too),  generalizing a question may lead to an almost trivial answer by forcing one to forget about irrelevant details.

**Bibliography**
Here is a [reference by Lenstra](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsites.math.leidenuniv.nl%2Falgebra%2FGSchemes.pdf&ei=0k0XVNmlK8TlavmOglg&usg=AFQjCNFMCiuoZMi6mGnEtN_eRtLJ5XG4FA&sig2=V7VpLX2OKZvB829brwgn5g) which, although it doesn't explicitly contain the  answer to the OP's question, is quite relevant.

Comment: The most shocking example of your remark, for me, is the way algebraic geometers have generalized the meaning of "local" so as to trivialize things. It is a great accomplishment :-)